# Cargar una Imagen desde la Galeria Android

Tags: android

Pulso en la imagen y me deja seleccionar una de la galería, pero cuando la selecciono no se cambia. Se que me falta una parte del código, alguien podría ayudarme con ello? Gracias!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final int PHOTO_SELECTED = 1;
    ImageButton fotoH;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            fotoH = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pruebah);

            fotoH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_SELECTED);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finalmente lo he solucionado. Dejo aquí el código

```
private static final int PICK_IMAGE = 100;
Uri imageUri;
ImageView foto_gallery;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    foto_gallery = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.foto_gallery);

    foto_gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openGallery();
        }
    });
}

private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        foto_gallery.setImageURI(imageUri);
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Este tipo de código funciona pero no todos los modelos, ¿Cuál podría ser el inconveniente?

Answer (score 3):

Estas accediendo a traves del método definido en la vista para realizar el intent,

```
public void onClick(View v) {
```

como una opción puedes definir en cada vista el indice del elemento por medio del Tag,

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:tag="0"
            android:src="@drawable/image" />
```

de esta forma puedes obtener el indice de la foto seleccionada:

```
        fotoH = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pruebah);

        //Obtiene el indice de la foto selecionada a travez de la etiqueta definida (tag).
        PHOTO_SELECTED = Integer.Parse(fotoH.getTag());

        fotoH.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_SELECTED);
            }
        });
```

Aunque es importante comentar que lo que realizas se debe realizar a traves de un Custom Intent Chooser, esto para abrir la foto en una aplicación que pueda manipular tu tipo de contenido, sería de esta forma:

```
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona Imagen"), PHOTO_SELECTED);
```